# Centos7 mod_wsgi python3 django timeout error 504 Gateway error

Tags: apache-2.4, python, httpd, mod-wsgi

I have been using apache for a django project. I need to upload a very large file in application. But I am getting Gateway timeout error 504.

I am using Centos7, httpd2.4, mos_wsgi, python3.48

```
#myapp.conf

Alias /static /opt/grameenphone-torque/static
<Directory /opt/grameenphone-torque/static>
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/grameenphone-torque/xcg_is>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess xcg_is python-path=/opt/grameenphone-torque:/opt/grameenphone-torque/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages request-timeout=6000 connect-timeout=6000 queue-timeout=6000
WSGIProcessGroup xcg_is
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/grameenphone-torque/xcg_is/wsgi.py
```

Comment: You set very short timeouts. You should increase those.

Comment: is 6000 in seconds or milliseconds ? Can you please tell me ? I want to set it for 30 minutes.

Comment: Those are milliseconds. So you need a lot more zeroes.

Comment: Now I tried with 600000 but did get same result. After almost 60 seconds I got 504 gateway error.

Answer (score 1):

Just add needed TimeOut to your VirtualHost section.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#timeout.
Like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ....
    TimeOut 600
    ....
```

Cause default is exactly 60 seconds